# Permitir que el usuario agregue un objeto en HTML con Django

Tags: html, django

estoy haciendo una app web en Django para restaurante/BAR y quiero que el usuario pueda agregar mas mesas o quitarlas de ser necesario en el espacio que muestro en la imagen.[image: imagen de las mesas]

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas agregar esas "Mesas" en tiempo real, vas a necesitar inyectar html a tu template, eso se puede hacer mediante javascript manipulando el DOM.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
    <!-- Teniendo esto dentro del body -->
<div class="container-fluid p-4">
    <div class="row" id="products">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Con este querySelector, declaro una variable que corresponde al div products
    var products = document.querySelector('#products');

    //Ahora escribo un pedazo de codigo HTML con las clases y estilos correspondientes
    const newProductTemplate = `
        <div class="col-xs-4 p-2">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{nombre}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {{descripcion}}
              <hr>
              ${{precio}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                DELETE
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      `;

    //Por ultimo, a "products" que es mi div, le inyecto el codigo que acabo de definir
    products.innerHTML += newProductTemplate;

</script>
```

Por supuesto que no vas a tener {{nombre}}, {{descripcion}}, {{precio}} en tu caso, porque los traigo de otra manera en mi codigo. Pero queria mostrarte como podias inyectar html en el documento. La accion que lo desencadenadera sera algun evento de js que dispongas.

Si necesitas persistir esas "mesas" en la BD pero necesitas conservar el agregarlas a tiempo real como te estoy mostrando, vas a necesitar un ajax que te ayude a mandar la informacion de la mesa a una vista que guarde la misma en el ORM.

---

La otra opción, menos dinamica, es que hagas algun boton o formulario que te agregue la mesa y recargues la pagina mostrando todas las mesas asociadas a un modelo que tengas, es decir, renderizando todo desde el backend.

Consultame si necesitas mas ayuda o un ejemplo mas especifico.
Saludos.